# Виртуальный хостинг: что обычно означает характеристика тарифа "N сайтов"?

Tags: хостинг

На многих базовых тарифах многих хостингов в числе прочего указывается ограничение на количество сайтов.

Как это можно понять? Допускаются ли при этом, например, поддомены? Я понимаю, что этот вопрос лучше адресовать напрямую хостингам, а не сюда, но я сейчас выбираю примерно из дюжины - тогда по-хорошему надо всех обзванивать. Может быть здесь есть какое-то общее определение понятия "сайт"?

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос очень философский и в конечном счете нужно уточнять у хостера. Но хостеры тоже не любят терять денег, поэтому, скорее всего их ответ будет таким, чтобы максимизировать прибыль.

Зная особенности некоторых хостеров, могу сказать, что под "сайтом" понимается некая сущность, которая существует как одно целое. То есть, если на Вашем сайте поддомены это просто что бы упростить навигацию - это один сайт (допустим так user1.domain.com, user2.domaint.com). Если же по разным поддоменам совершенно разные сайты (например, на одном жумла, на втором вордпресс) - то это уже похоже на два разных сайта и хостер это может именно так и трактовать. Но вполне может быть, что Вы написали "прослойку", которая позволяет разным cms работать с одной базой и все эти cms показывают одни и те же данные, то это может быть засчитано как один сайт. Но вполне возможно, что придется объяснять это хостеру и тому подобное.

Но вот если на поддоменах живут отдельные сайты для других пользователей (например, как narod.ru или ucoz), то тут вряд ли хостер будет считать это одним сайтом.

Если же Вы продолжаете сомневаться - купите себе vds (или даже полноценное железо) и там таких проблем нет. Там обычно ограничения, которые понятны (траффик, место на диске).

Answer (score 1):

Это напрямую указано в условиях/описании тарифа.